# Spark for realtime OLAP queries

Tags: apache-spark

I have IoT data streaming in via Kafka, and would like to use Spark SQL to analyze it.  I was planning on persisting data to S3 using [Sector](https://github.com/pinterest/secor), but there will be a delay of a few minutes while the batch of data gets collected before being written to S3.

How can I make Spark query both the streaming data, and the historical data on S3?  Do I run two queries - one with Spark Streaming, and one Spark SQL, and try to combine the results?

Or do I need to use an OLTP database for this type of functionality?  I wanted to independently scale compute and storage, which is why I went with Spark + S3.

Comment: Seems like a job for [druid](http://druid.io/).